# Resharper Unit Test Runner failed to run tests (System.BadImageFormatException) in release

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, badimageformatexception

Using VS 10.0.40219.1, Resharper 8.2.1
I had switched over to a Release build and forgotten about it. Next time I tried to run any of the unit tests, I got the error
"Resharper Unit Test Runner failed to run tests" System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'HearThis, Version...
Eventually I figured out that I was in Release mode and switched back to Debug, where all my tests run just fine. At the moment, at least, I'm not too terribly worried about needing to run my unit tests in release mode, but it's hard to say that I'll **never** need to do that. The question is *why* is it failing. On the TeamCity build server, it successfully does a release build and and runs the tests. I know I've run tests in release mode in the past, but I just tried another project, and it also fails in the same way. Is there possibly some new bug in Resharper's Test Runner, or could something have gotten corrupted, deleted, ???

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A `BadImageFormatException` is usually due to a mixup with the 32/64 bit settings. Make sure your test assembly has the same bit-ness as your assemblies being tested. For example, if you're on a 64 bit machine, and any of the assemblies require 32 bit (perhaps you're p/invoking into a 32 bit native dll), then the test assembly should also be 32 bit.

ReSharper runs tests in an external process, and supports 32/64 bit. It uses the test assembly's settings to decide which version of the external process to run.

Comment: I knew about the 32/64-bit issue, but I didn't realize (or at least didn't consider) that:
a) This could be set differently for the Release/Debug configurations
b) Choosing Any CPU for the tests would build a 64-bit DLL (the DLL under test was explicitly set to build x86 in both Debug and Release)
c) I was "sure" that I had run tests in Release mode for the other project I tried this on, but apparently being "sure" isn't the same as being "correct."